# Overwriting Quill default key bindings

Tags: quill

I am trying to overwrite the 'list autofill' default key binding. I'm basing my configuration on the documentation (http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/#configuration) but it doesn't seem to be working; the default handler is firing and mine doesn't seem to have been added (based on checking `quill.keyboard.bindings`).

Here's my code (this is basically a copy of the binding from the keyboard module, with edits to the handler):

```
var bindings = {
  'list autofill': {
    key: ' ',
    collapsed: true,
    format: { list: false , 'testListNum': false, 'testListBul': false},
    prefix: /^(1\.|-)$/,
    handler: function(range, context) {
      let length = context.prefix.length;
      this.quill.scroll.deleteAt(range.index - length, length);
      if (length === 1){
        this.quill.formatLine(range.index - length, 1, 'testListBul',  true, Quill.sources.USER);
      }else{this.quill.formatLine(range.index - length, 1, 'testListNum',  true, Quill.sources.USER);}
      this.quill.setSelection(range.index - length, Quill.sources.SILENT);
    }
  }
};
```

and then:

```
var editor = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    keyboard: {bindings: bindings},
    toolbar: '#toolbar',
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

is there more to it? Can this type of 'custom' key binding not be overwritten? Does my handler need to be somehow more specific than the default?

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine: http://codepen.io/quill/pen/XjRaQB

Comment: Thank you for checking; I rebuilt my code and realized I had a stray duplicate initialization of my editor later in my code that was overwriting the real one.